# Reading programs gives values of 0

Tags: java, arrays

so whats going on is that im trying to read this PlayerData.txt file:

```
Dirk-Nowitzki (Dallas-Mavericks) 24 11 5

Dwayne-Wade (Miami-Heat) 36 8 6

LeBron-James (Miami-Heat) 20 8 10

Shawn-Marion (Dallas-Mavericks) 20 6 6

Chris-Bosh (Miami-Heat) 12 4 5

Jason-Terry (Dallas-Mavericks) 16 3 6

DeShawn-Stevenson (Dallas-Mavericks) 12 3 5

Mario-Chalmers (Miami-Heat) 9 1 4

Peja-Stojakovic (Dallas-Mavericks) 2 1 1

Mike Miller (Miami-Heat) 7 2 3
```

---

im reading the three integers, which are points, rebounds, and assists respectively
and im printing them out in the output window, but im getting 0's for all of my integer values.
im pretty sure that this is a pretty easy fix and im making beginner mistakes, but i just dont know where....
can someone please tell me what im doing wrong and/or what i need to do to fix it? thanks in advance.

Here's my code (ps im not allowed to use bufferreader or arraylist):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class CPT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("PlayerData.txt"));

        int Points[] = new int[10];

        int Rebounds[] = new int[10];

        int Assists[] = new int[10];


        for (int i=0;i<=10;i++){
            while (scan.hasNextInt()){
                Points[i]=scan.nextInt();
            }
            while (scan.hasNextInt()){
                Rebounds[i]=scan.nextInt();
            }
            while (scan.hasNextInt()){
                Assists[i]=scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<=9;i++){
            System.out.print(Points[i]+"\t"+Rebounds[i]+"\t"+Assists[i]+"\n");
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote, your first for loop will trigger an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception.  You are looping through indices 0 thru 10 (inclusive), whereas your arrays are 0 thru 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to get ints:

```
scan.hasNextInt()
```

However, your file has these lines:

> Dirk-Nowitzki (Dallas-Mavericks) 24 11 5

You need to read the text first, then parse the ints.

Answer (score 1):

Like AnubianNoob said, you have to discard the names and teams first then parse your data, and instead of using `for` loops and possibly overrun your input values, try using `while(scan.hasNext());` and `for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)` instead, it can make your program more extendable if you decide to add extra data, and you don't have to keep track of how long your individual arrays are.

EDIT: also your last line says `Mike Miller` not `Mike-Miller`, so it might cause a hiccup while parsing through

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly glancing at your code, I just see a couple problems, though I don't think they directly relate to your issue.

First off, your FOR loop that reads in the values will loop 11 times, exceeding the size of your arrays. Use either i<10 or i<=9, for consistency I would use i<=9 since that is what you put for your second FOR loop.

Secondly, I don't think you want to run a WHILE loop when reading your data. Your code will only insert all of the ints into your Points array. You want to change these to IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else has pointed out, the first loop will have an error since it will loop 11 times instead of 10 times.

For loading in the data, I would take a different approach and read each line into a string and then split up the string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] split = line.split(" ");

    Points[i] = new Integer(split[2]);
    Rebounds[i] = new Integer(split[3]);
    Assists[i] = new Integer(split[4]);
}
```

Basically each line of text is read by the scanner. The line is then split up into an array by " ". For example, the first line of text would be split like

split[0] = Dirk-Nowitzki

split[1] = (Dallas-Mavericks)

split[2] = 24

split[3] = 11

split[4] = 5

After this has been set up, a new integer is created and then saved into the correct array. The above code has some errors and needs to be cleaned up a bit. You should include a provision which checks whether or not the scanner has a new line of code, and make sure that it ignores blank spaces and only includes lines that actually have text.